# How to resolve error "Failed to load MailChimp PHP library. Please refer to the installation requirements."?

Tags: emails, composer

I'm try to set up [Mailchimp](https://www.drupal.org/project/mailchimp) module but i keep geeting 
Failed to load MailChimp PHP library. Please refer to the installation requirements.

My steps:

- disable [mailchimp](https://www.drupal.org/project/mailchimp) module
- install composer_manager package locally
- run: curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php on my root
- change composer.json(which lay on my root) - see it below
- run: php composer.phar install --no-dev
- mailchimp/mailchimp directory is installed in my /vendor folder
- clear cache, re=enable module but still getting the error. In my report i see that the module cannot be found.

What i'm doing wrong??

```
{
    "name": "drupal/composer_manager",
    "type": "drupal-module",
    "description": "Composer Manager is a bridge to best-in-breed, standards compliant PHP libraries that are managed by Composer and Packagist.",
    "homepage": "http://drupal.org/project/composer_manager",
    "license": "GPL-2.0",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Chris Pliakas",
            "email": "opensource@chrispliakas.com",
            "role": "Project Lead"
        },
        {
            "name": "See contributors",
            "homepage": "http://drupal.org/node/1929436/committers",
            "role": "Developer"
        }
    ],
    "support": {
        "issues": "http://drupal.org/project/issues/composer_manager"
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.0",
        "mailchimp/mailchimp": ">=2.0.4"
    }
}
```

MailChimp module => 7x.3-3

mailchimp library => 2.04

Comment: Have a look at this thread  https://www.drupal.org/node/2054037 It might be helpful for you.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some steps to troubleshoot this error according to this thread: [Issue #2054037 Failed to load MailChimp PHP library. Please refer to the installation requirements.](https://www.drupal.org/node/2054037) (provided by @rtome, above)

- Re-read the instructions in MailChimp module's README.txt
- Clear the cache
- Ensure [Libraries](https://drupal.org/project/libraries) module is installed and is working properly
- Ensure Mailchimp library is located at *sites/all/libraries/mailchimp*
- Check your versions:

> MailChimp module 7.x-2.x requires MailChimp library 1.3
>   MailChimp module > 7.x-3.x requires MailChimp library 2.04

- If MailChimp library updated, reinstall MailChimp module

Answer (score 0):

The mailchimp module 7.x-2.x and 7.x-3.x branches rely on MailChimp’s API version 2.0 and has became unsupported by MailChimp at the end of the year 2016.To upgrade to the latest version, please go through with the following link http://cgit.drupalcode.org/mailchimp/tree/README.txt.