# how to create signup form with MailChimp module

Tags: 7, emails

I want to follow the tutorial at https://drupalize.me/videos/create-your-first-mailing-list-and-sign-form?p=2235 but I'm stumbling as soon as we get to create sign up forms in the `MailChimp` module configuration. I don't see a "SIGNUP FORMS" tab but instead I get 5 red error messages on top that say **Failed to load MailChimp PHP library. Please refer to the installation requirements.** and if I look under `/admin/reports/status`, I see **The MailChimp MCAPI library could not be found.** under the `MailChimp` module. How can I get these resolved?

Comment: Try [this answer](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/170757/28700) for [How to resolve error “Failed to load MailChimp PHP library..."](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/158467/how-to-resolve-error-failed-to-load-mailchimp-php-library-please-refer-to-the)

Answer (score 2):

I get it. You’ve just signed up for Mailchimp and set up your first list. You want to put a signup form on your Drupal 8 (probably works in D7 as well) website so visitors can start signing up for your newsletter or announcements. Here's how you place a signup block. I know this is a late answer, but hopefully it will help someone. To get through this process you have to clear cache a lot. Here's what worked for me.

Install and enable the mailchimp module and the Mailchimp_signup module. Set up the API key with your mailchimp API clear cache (on the command line you can type ‘drush cr’ or you can do it in the admin menu | config page | performance link | clear all caches button).

Go to admin/config/services/mailchimp/signup and add a signup form. Give it a name and remember the name since that’s what you’ll search for when you’re ready to place the block. Check the ‘Block’ checkbox. Choose at least one list that you’ve set up on Mailchimp’s website or on the Lists tab. Save the form.

Refresh cache ‘drush cr’ again.

Go to the Structure | Block layout tab. Choose a region where you would like the signup tab and choose ‘Place block’. Search for the name you used when naming your signup form. Choose it and ‘Save block’.

Now go to your site and observe your work. Your form will appear in the area you specified.

Answer (score 0):

The module isn't able to find the required library. You can follow the instructions on the [project page](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/mailchimp) or the follow the [Drupalize video tutorial](https://drupalize.me/videos/install-mailchimp-module-and-dependencies?p=2235) in the series you linked to. If you've already followed those steps, there's a good chance you've not set the correct ownership/permissions on the API libraries so that the Drupal can load/execute the API code.